# Pattern for moving javascript out of the markup

Tags: knockout.js, refactoring, rendering, episerver

**tl;dr** How do I refactor a typical .NET+KnockoutJS site using lots of server generated blocks (controllers) into one where all js is loaded separately from the markup?

Up until now all my foray into front-end development has been new projects, built from the ground using modern tooling and workflows, such as React, Redux, isomorphic rendering, etc. Yesterday a legacy project (ok, made three years ago) landed on my lap, and it features "blocks" (an EPi Server term basically meaning templates) such as this:

**MySuperSlider.ascx**

```
<!-- ko foreach: products() -->
<div class="my-super-slider">
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: ProductUrl }">
        <h1  data-bind="text: name"></h1>
        <img src="" data-bind="attr: { src : image.uri }"
    </a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Make a call to the back-end to retrieve the product data used 
// in the KO template above and apply it
ko.applyBindings(new SliderBlock(
            '<%# ProductsController.GetServiceUrl(ProductsController.BlockUrl, Request.Url)%>',
            '<%# CurrentPage.PageLink.ID %>',
            '<%# GetBlockId() %>',
            '<%# (CurrentPage as SitePageDataBase) == null?string.Empty:(CurrentPage as SitePageDataBase).ProductPageUrl %>?id=',
            '<%# ContentLanguageCode %>',
            "<%# SliderContentBlock.ClientID %>"), document.getElementById("<%# SliderContentBlock.ClientID %>"));

</script>
```

Blocks, such as this one, are being reused all over the site, but with different settings (ref `SliderContentBlock.ClientID` which would fetch data for that current block). The fact that the referenced variables are unique for each block instance and rendered at runtime makes it impossible/hard to split the js out. Except possibly using some `data` attributes that could later be picked up?

**Problem: `<script>` tags cannot be moved out of `<head>`**

It is currently impossible to move `<script>` tags out of `<head>`, thus blocking the rendering pipeline. Neither moving after them after `<body>` or using `async` or `defer` attributes is possible as this would make any inline `<script>` blocks referring to the `ko` variable break.

So what is a good strategy for refactoring the above code into something that will work regardless of whether the knockout library has been loaded or not?

**Hacky solution**

The fastest (and probably most brittle) solution would be to create an array to hold initialization functions that could then be executed later on. Something like

```
<head>
    <script>window.initFuncs = [];</script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <!--  inline code pushing init code in the queue -->
    ...
    <script>initFuncs.forEach( fn => fn() );</script>
</body>
```

Then all I would need to do to defer execution of the above javascript would be to wrap it in a `window.initFuncs.push( () => { ko.applyBindings(/* js goes  here */) })`

This would work, but does not exactly seem like the way to go. But this problem must have been solved a million times before (?). How does other Knockout developers do this?

I cannot simply move *all* of the javascript (as it is) out into separate files, as variables are being inserted into the markup during server rendering.

**Attempt at better solution**

I am not a .NET developer, but I feel the logic in the template with all the variable substitution would be better done in the backing code, instead of pushing all the details into the front-end. Not sure how that would be done, though.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Change your .net controllers to output json, and make ajax requests from a separate js file referenced in a `<script>` tag in your html.

-or-

2. If you still want your .net template to render the data directly to the html, without separate ajax requests, then fine, but don't have it write out js functions or similar. This will be difficult to maintain. Instead, set up a javascript object, similar to what you suggest, but have it contain only data. Then in a separate js file referenced in a `<script>` tag in your html, read the data from that object to init your front-end view-model or other js functions.

   e.g.

   **.ascx**

   ```
   <!-- ko foreach: products() -->
   <div class="my-super-slider">
       <a data-bind="attr: { href: ProductUrl }">
           <h1  data-bind="text: Name"></h1>
       </a>
   </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <script>
     MyPageContext = {};
     MyPageContext.ProductId = '<%# (CurrentPage as SitePageDataBase) == null?string.Empty:(CurrentPage as SitePageDataBase).ProductId %>';
     MyPageContext.OtherData = '...';        
   </script>
   <script src="productpage.js"></script>
   ```

   **productpage.js**

   ```
    ko.applyBindings(new SliderBlock(MyPageContext.ProductId, MyPageContext.OtherData, ...));
     ...
   ```

   Also, there is no reason these scripts can't come at the end of your  content. Knockout will not attempt to be run until you call `ko.applyBindings`

Comment: Note that you can also set up your block types to _require_ client resources, such as JavaScript and CSS. That way, the client resources will only be included in the markup if said block(s) are rendered on the page. See [the Episerver documentation](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Framework/7/Client-Resources/Client-Resources/#Requiring_client_resources).

Comment: @Peter Miller: actually there are quite a few issues here that makes the approaches invalid. For one: EPiServer is a CMS featuring a drag-n-drop interface for building pages out of pages and blocks; this is not a custom solution. We do already use controllers outputting json in this very example (this was unclear, but the `SliderBlock` function does an ajax call to populate the slider view). As such, html will be rendered anyhow. The second issue is " there is no reason these scripts can't come at the end of your content". yes there is, as the variables are block dependent and added at runtime

Comment: @TedNyberg: while that is nice for optimization, as a sort of dependency  management for the library bundles your blocks require, it does not really fix the core issue here. Splitting out js while still being able to refer to the server generated block-specific variables later on.

Comment: A last reservation is that creating `MyPageContext` objects inline like that would fail as soon as you start having multiple blocks on the same page. That is why I found using data attributes to be a more flexible solution, although similar in the idea. Thanks for answering, anyhow :-)

Comment: @oligofren to your last point: In each block, you could do `MyPageContext = MyPageContext || {};` This would act to initialise the object if it is the first suck block, or add to it if it is not.

Comment: @PeterMiller: that doesn't really fix much. All the attributes, such as ProductId, would still be overwritten. One workaround could be to push the context objects on an array that could be iterated on. That would work.

Comment: @oligofren actually, they would not be rewritten. `MyPageContext = MyPageContext || {};` will not overwrite any attributes. It will set `MyPageContext` to the previous value of `MyPageContext` if it was not null or undefined or false. If it was any of those things, and *only* if it was one of those things, it will set it to `{}` (a blank object).

Comment: @PeterMiller Yes, that's fine, but I was referring to the attributes of that object. You would only be able to have one unique identifier per page. For instance, each instance of a block has a unique block id. That attribute would be overwritten. Granted, it's easy to fix by just adding the context object to an array, but that was not in the posted answer.

Comment: ... And I already mentioned the array initializer approach in the question as what I thought of as a brittle/hacky solution. Global variables all over the code feels a bit 2005.

Comment: @oligofren I think there's still a misunderstanding here. The attributes of the object will not be overwritten. Although I agree your situation may be too restrictive to even follow this technique.

Answer (score 1):

While not in EPi, this is what I tend to do:

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
   ...

   public ClientSideModel ClientSideModel {get;set;}
}

public class ClientSideModel
{
    public string ProductId {get;set;}

    ....

    public HtmlString ToJson()
    {
        return new HtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
    }
}
```

And in my markup:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(@Model.ClientSideModel.ToJson()));
```

Comment: That's not really conceptually any different. You are still mixing markup and js in the rendered block, which is what I would like to avoid. I wanted a pattern to move js out of the server rendering. Of course I see that you here explicitly inject the json directly into the js, but in this specific example, it is actually avoided by choice, as the retrieval of the images takes a few seconds.

The interesting bit is how to move js out of the rendering while still being able to have individual data per block.

Comment: But I'll give you the ToJson() method is very nice when inserting that data into a data attribute tag!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an additional answer here myself, detailing the approach I found the best so far. In this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579349/how-to-separate-inline-javascript-from-dynamically-generated-content-in-express?rq=1) from a Node developer, which also concerned removing inline js, the best answer there seemed to be to let the server render the data needed for the individual blocks into data attributes. You can then later on retrieve the dom node(s), extract the data from the data attributes, and do whatever js needed to make it work.

So for the above example, the last `<script>` block could have been omitted.

Instead we would insert one or more data tag into the slider, such as this:

```
<div 
    class="my-super-slider" 
    data-model='{ 
        "url" : "<%# ProductsController.GetServiceUrl(ProductsController.BlockUrl, Request.Url)%>",
        "pageLinkId" : "<%# CurrentPage.PageLink.ID %>",
        "blockId" : "<%# GetBlockId() %>",
        "lang" : "<%# ContentLanguageCode %>",
        "clientId" : "<%# SliderContentBlock.ClientID %>"
    }'
>
```

Then we could just load any js async that would query for `.my-super-slider` elements and use the data attributes to start doing any relevant magic. This solves all of the synchronous issues and opens up for a whole new dimension of performance optimizations.

*(The data attribute approach is tangentially similar to @MaciejGrzyb's answer, but the EPiServer controllers creating the data is outside my reach).*